# How do I set up a domain-like hostname on IRC?

Tags: irc, domain-name, irc-bouncer

I own a domain name, and a virtual private server. On that server I've installed ZNC as a bouncer for my IRC connection, and when connected through it  the hostname is just a random hash of letters and numbers, or the server's IP if I set `-x` on myself.

I know many BNC providers offer custom hosts for domains, but how would I use my own domain with my own bouncer? I've looked thoroughly and I can't seem to find an answer to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's standard [reverse DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS):

1. Choose a domain, or a subdomain, that you control. Let's say, `example.com.`.
2. Point the domain to your server's IP address using a standard `A` or `AAAA` record.

   ```
   alex.example.com. A    192.0.2.1
                     AAAA 2001:db8::42
   ```
3. Configure the [rDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS) to resolve your IP address back to that domain. rDNS uses `PTR` records under the special `in-addr.arpa.` and `ip6.arpa.` domains, but usually you don't have to deal with them directly, as most VPS hosts will have a control panel option to change the rDNS for your server's addresses. For a home Internet connection, you would have to ask your ISP.

   ```
   1.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa. PTR alex.example.com.

   2.4.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.b.d.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa. PTR alex.example.com
   ```

If you have recently connected to the IRC server, it will have cached the previous data – remember to wait until its cache expires.

Also remember that almost all IRC servers require forward and reverse DNS to be identical:

- `alex.example.com.` → `192.0.2.1`
- `192.0.2.1` → `alex.example.com.`

Comment: I don't see an option to change my rDNS or PTR record in my VPS, but I can change the server's hostname. Would this be it?

Comment: It could be. Try changing it to your desired domain, then check using something like `dig +trace -x <ipaddr>` if the PTR record was updated.

Comment: at the last sentence, how do I check that?

Comment: Using standard DNS lookup tools, one of which was named in the same sentence?